# Can you deploy a non-java application with Cloudbees AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment?

Tags: cloudbees, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This article: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/ElasticBeanstalk
suggests that only java is supported.  Is it possible to deploy a ruby app (for instance) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this seems to work just fine.  In our case, we preferred to do our ruby deployments to beanstalk from Jenkins rather than with the git/eb tools.  We zipped up our workspace as a post-build action **with a .war extension** (instead of zip), archived that artifact with another post-build action, and then all the machinery was available at that point in Jenkins (at least via [Cloudbees](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/ElasticBeanstalk) plugins) to set up an AWS Beanstalk deploy.